# Remove Scrollbar From Viewport Ext JS 4

Tags: extjs4, scrollbar, viewport

I'm getting a scrollbar in the Viewport, how can I remove it.

I know that is a strange situation because in the documentation we have this :

```
The Viewport does not provide scrolling, so child Panels within the Viewport 
should provide for scrolling if needed using the autoScroll config.
```

from [viewport sencha doc](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.container.Viewport)

**My Viewport :**

```
Ext.define('MyViewport', {
   extend : 'Ext.container.Viewport',

   layout : 'border',
   padding : '5 5 5 5',
   defaults: {
       split: true,
       autoScroll : false
   },
   initComponent : function() {
       this.items = [{
         region: 'north',
         height: 70,
         width : '100%',
         split : false,
         padding : '0 0 5 0',
         items:[{
               //here some items
         }]
    },{
        region:'west',
        collapsible: true,
        width: 210,
        maxWidth : 210,
        autoScroll : false,
        items:[{
               //here some items
         }]
    },{
        region:'center',
        id : 'workspace',
        //here I add panels dynamically
    }];
    this.callParent(arguments);
      }
 });
```

am I missing somthing ?!

Comment: Are you getting scroll bars in the viewport itself, or in the child panels?

Comment: I'm getting the scroll bar in the viewport itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the docs say, a viewport will never get a scrollbar applied directly on to it automatically.

But each of your regions are `Ext.panel.Panel` components by default which automatically get a scrollbar on overflow.

Try adding a `layout: fit` config to your viewport.

If that doesn't handle it, add the same config to the panel component that has the scroll bars.

Comment: I can't change the viewport's layout to fit because I need border layout to seperate page zones.

Comment: Did you try adding `layout: fit` to the viewport region panels?

Comment: Yes I have tested `layout: fit` and the page elements become desordered

Comment: When I add `layout: fit` in the viewport I get desordered elements as I have already said, and when I add it to panels the problem **not** resoled. Thanks.